# Shopify Buy Button Minimum Quantity

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm currently using the [Shopify Buy Button](https://www.shopify.com/buy-button).

For the most part, I just copy and pasted the embed code and didn't change much.

I have a few products that require a that they buy a quantity of 5 or more of said item.

The typical add to bag button adds only one and inside the shopping cart, when pressed, adds/subtracts one.

---

## My Question(s)

- Is there a way to set a default quantity when clicking on ADD TO CART?
- And is there a way to add a default subtract/minus on said item

*NOTE: I don't want this for all items, only the specific item that the embed buy code is for.*

---

I've searched the [default compenents](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/blob/master/src/defaults/components.js) and the [developer section](https://github.com/Shopify/buy-button-js/blob/master/docs/customization/index.md) and found the following:

```
var events = {
  addVariantToCart: function (product) {},
  updateQuantity: function (product) {},
 ...
}
```

I assume this might be what I am looking for but I can't find any solidified details on how to update said product.

If anyone could help or guide me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

---

**My Embed Code**

```
<div id='product-component-ITEM-ID'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy){if(window.ShopifyBuy.UI){ShopifyBuyInit();}else{loadScript();}}else{loadScript();}
  function loadScript() {var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.src = scriptURL;(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;}
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({domain: 'DOMAIN.myshopify.com',apiKey: 'API-KEY',appId: '6'});
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function(ui){ui.createComponent('product',{id:["ITEM-ID"],node:document.getElementById('product-component-{{page.item_id}}'),moneyFormat:'%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',

    options:{
      "product":{
        "variantId":"all",
        "width":"240px",
        "contents":{
          "img":false,
          "imgWithCarousel":false,
          "title":false,
          "variantTitle":false,
          "price":false,
          "description":false,
          "buttonWithQuantity":false,
          "quantity":false
        },
        "text":{
          "button":"ADD TO BAG"
        },
        "styles":{
          "product":{
            "text-align":"left",
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "max-width":"100%",
              "margin-left":"0",
              "margin-bottom":"50px"
            }
          },
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            "padding-left":"35px",
            "padding-right":"35px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "title":{
            "font-size":"26px"
          },
          "price":{
            "font-size":"18px"
          },
          "quantityInput":{
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
          },
          "compareAt":{
            "font-size":"15px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "cart":{
        "contents":{
          "button":true
        },
        "styles":{
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "footer":{
            "background-color":"#ffffff"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "modalProduct":{
        "contents":{
          "img":false,
          "imgWithCarousel":true,
          "variantTitle":false,
          "buttonWithQuantity":true,
          "button":false,
          "quantity":false
        },
        "styles":{
          "product":{
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "max-width":"100%",
              "margin-left":"0px",
              "margin-bottom":"0px"
            }
          },
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            "padding-left":"35px",
            "padding-right":"35px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "quantityInput":{
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "toggle":{
        "iframe":false,
        "sticky":false,
        "templates":{
          "icon":'<i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-lg darkgrey" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        },
        "contents":{
          "icon":true,
          "title":false
        },
        "events":{
          afterInit:function (component)      {
            document.getElementById('cart-toggle').appendChild(component.node);
          },

        },
        "order":[
          'count',
          'icon'
        ],
        "styles":{
          "toggle":{
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "count":{
            "font-size":"13px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "productSet":{
        "styles":{
          "products":{
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "margin-left":"-20px"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }

    );});}})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: is the template a single buy button?

Comment: I've never used the button before, but the `"quantity":false` in the code you posted is probably worth looking into.

Comment: @雰囲気が読めない人 Nope, that just sets whether the quantity tools are visible or not. Doesn't help in this situation. I'm working on a solution right now, however, nearly got it working.

Comment: Couldn't one could manually create the html that is created by that option as a select with the appropriate quantity values in them?

Comment: the problem i've found is that - even if you create a template - you need to figure out how to set the minimum quantity for the buy button;

Comment: @DenisTsoi yes it is a single buy button. The issue I'm finding now is that I can't figure out how to update the product quantity in any form from the cart event `updateItemQuantity`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few hours of experimentation, this is the solution I came up with. My testing so far has shown it to be robust and reliable, but if you find any issues please let me know and I'll see what I can do.

The following is the code, using the example code from the [Shopify Buy Button homepage](https://www.shopify.com.au/buy-button). Unfortunately this won't run in a snippet, but if you put that in an HTML file and run it you can test it.

---

### Full Example Code

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='product-component-05cfb487fb6' data-minqty='5'></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
        domain: 'embeds.myshopify.com',
        apiKey: '952162710f94aa7b7644b14b2a94f4a3',
        appId: '6',
    });

    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function(ui) {
        ui.createComponent('product', {
            id: [3030475907],
            node: document.getElementById('product-component-05cfb487fb6'),
            moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
            options: {
                "product": {
                    "styles": {
                        "button": {
                            "background-color": "#292929",
                            ":hover": {
                                "background-color": "#464646"
                            },
                            ":focus": {
                                "background-color": "#464646"
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    "events": {
                        "addVariantToCart": function(product) {
                            product.model.selectedQuantity = 1;
                            var minQty = $(product.node).data('minqty');
                            if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty) {
                                product.updateQuantity(function() {
                                    return minQty - (product.cart.model.lineItemCount);
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "cart": {
                    "events": {
                        "updateItemQuantity": function(cart) {
                            for (let i = 0; i < ui.components.product.length; i++) {
                                var product = ui.components.product[i];
                                var node = product.node;
                                if ($(node).data('minqty')) {
                                    var minQty = $(node).data('minqty');
                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                        setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui);
                                    }, 1);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
}

function setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui) {
    if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty && product.cart.model.lineItemCount > 0) {
        $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper').find('iframe').contents().find("div[id='" + product.cart.model.lineItems[0].id + "']").find('.shopify-buy__quantity-decrement').click();
    }
}

(function() {
    var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
    window.ShopifyBuy && window.ShopifyBuy.UI ? ShopifyBuyInit() : loadScript();

    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = scriptURL;
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
        script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
    }
})();
```

---

### In-depth Explanation

This works by listening to two events from the Shopify Buy Button: `addVariantToCart` and `updateItemQuantity`. The first thing you have to do is add a `data-minqty` attribute to the product div. We'll use that data attribute later.

```
<div id='product-component-05cfb487fb6' data-minqty='5'></div>
```

The first event fires when clicking Add to Cart. We'll listen to it so we can make it add `minQty` items to the cart (in our example, this is 5).

```
"addVariantToCart": function(product) {
    product.model.selectedQuantity = 1;
    var minQty = $(product.node).data('minqty');
    if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty) {
        product.updateQuantity(function() {
            return minQty - product.cart.model.lineItemCount;
        });
    }
}
```

What that does is first set the selected quantity of the item to 1. This is because the selected quantity is automatically set to the last-added quantity, and if we're adding the item to the cart for the first time it will == `minQty` (i.e. 5). Then we find the minimum quantity from the data attribute we added earlier (`product.node` is the product's div element). We check if the quantity is less than `minQty`, and if it is, we run `updateQuantity` on the product. For some reason it's relative, so we run it with the difference between `minQty` and `product.cart.model.lineItemCount`, which is the current quantity.

The second event fires when changing the quantity from the cart itself. We listen to it so we can ensure customers can't reduce the quantity below `minQty`.

```
"updateItemQuantity": function(cart) {
    for (let i = 0; i < ui.components.product.length; i++) {
        var product = ui.components.product[i];
        var node = product.node;
        if ($(node).data('minqty')) {
            var minQty = $(node).data('minqty');
            setTimeout(function() {
                setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui);
            }, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Since we don't know exactly which item in the cart had its quantity changed, we go through them all and just check if they have a `minQty`, and if they have it, whether or not they're below. Then we use `setTimeout` because this event is fired *before* the quantity is updated, so if we change it right here it just gets reset. We call this function:

```
function setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui) {
    if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty && product.cart.model.lineItemCount > 0) {
        $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper').find('iframe').contents().find("div[id='" + product.cart.model.lineItems[0].id + "']").find('.shopify-buy__quantity-decrement').click();
    }
}
```

This function checks if the new quantity is less than `minQty`. If it's not, we do nothing (and let the quantity be updated normally). If it is, we want to remove the item from the cart. There's no "remove" button (it normally relies on lowering the quantity to 0 to be removed from the cart), and since we have a minimum quantity this can't happen, so we need to check for this and manually remove it. We just simulate a click on the "quantity decrement" button. We only need to do this once because each time we do it fires `updateItemQuantity` so it self-loops until the item is removed.

---

### Integrated with Your Code

I couldn't test your code directly, but I've added my changes to your code so hopefully you'll be able to figure it out. It does require jQuery because I don't know enough native Javascript for doing what I needed to do.

```
<div id='product-component-ITEM-ID' data-minqty='5'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy){if(window.ShopifyBuy.UI){ShopifyBuyInit();}else{loadScript();}}else{loadScript();}
  function loadScript() {var script = document.createElement('script');script.async = true;script.src = scriptURL;(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;}
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({domain: 'DOMAIN.myshopify.com',apiKey: 'API-KEY',appId: '6'});
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function(ui){ui.createComponent('product',{id:["ITEM-ID"],node:document.getElementById('product-component-{{page.item_id}}'),moneyFormat:'%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',

    options:{
      "product":{
        "variantId":"all",
        "width":"240px",
        "contents":{
          "img":false,
          "imgWithCarousel":false,
          "title":false,
          "variantTitle":false,
          "price":false,
          "description":false,
          "buttonWithQuantity":false,
          "quantity":false
        },
        "events": {
          "addVariantToCart": function(product) {
            product.model.selectedQuantity = 1;
            var minQty = $(product.node).data('minqty');
            if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty) {
              product.updateQuantity(function() {
                return minQty - (product.cart.model.lineItemCount);
              });
            }
          }
        }
        "text":{
          "button":"ADD TO BAG"
        },
        "styles":{
          "product":{
            "text-align":"left",
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "max-width":"100%",
              "margin-left":"0",
              "margin-bottom":"50px"
            }
          },
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            "padding-left":"35px",
            "padding-right":"35px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "title":{
            "font-size":"26px"
          },
          "price":{
            "font-size":"18px"
          },
          "quantityInput":{
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
          },
          "compareAt":{
            "font-size":"15px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "cart":{
        "contents":{
          "button":true
        },
        "events": {
          "updateItemQuantity": function(cart) {
            for (let i = 0; i < ui.components.product.length; i++) {
              var product = ui.components.product[i];
              var node = product.node;
              if ($(node).data('minqty')) {
                var minQty = $(node).data('minqty');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui);
                }, 1);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        "styles":{
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "footer":{
            "background-color":"#ffffff"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "modalProduct":{
        "contents":{
          "img":false,
          "imgWithCarousel":true,
          "variantTitle":false,
          "buttonWithQuantity":true,
          "button":false,
          "quantity":false
        },
        "styles":{
          "product":{
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "max-width":"100%",
              "margin-left":"0px",
              "margin-bottom":"0px"
            }
          },
          "button":{
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px",
            "padding-left":"35px",
            "padding-right":"35px",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "border-radius":"0px",
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "quantityInput":{
            "font-size":"13px",
            "padding-top":"14.5px",
            "padding-bottom":"14.5px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "toggle":{
        "iframe":false,
        "sticky":false,
        "templates":{
          "icon":'<i class="fa fa-shopping-bag fa-lg darkgrey" aria-hidden="true"></i>'
        },
        "contents":{
          "icon":true,
          "title":false
        },
        "events":{
          afterInit:function (component)      {
            document.getElementById('cart-toggle').appendChild(component.node);
          },

        },
        "order":[
          'count',
          'icon'
        ],
        "styles":{
          "toggle":{
            "font-family":"Lato,sans-serif",
            "background-color":"#393a39",
            ":hover":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            ":focus":{
              "background-color":"#333433"
            },
            "font-weight":"normal"
          },
          "count":{
            "font-size":"13px"
          }
        },
        "googleFonts":[
          "Lato"
        ]
      },
      "productSet":{
        "styles":{
          "products":{
            "@media(min-width:601px)":{
              "margin-left":"-20px"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }

    );});}})();

    function setProductQuantity(node, product, minQty, ui) {
      if (product.cart.model.lineItemCount < minQty && product.cart.model.lineItemCount > 0) {
        $('.shopify-buy-cart-wrapper').find('iframe').contents().find("div[id='" + product.cart.model.lineItems[0].id + "']").find('.shopify-buy__quantity-decrement').click();
      }
    }
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I'm aware this doesn't allow removing items from the cart just yet, I'm editing to fix that now.

Comment: My man! I appreciate all you're hard work. We are almost there. It looks like the add to cart if the product quantity for that specific item is < `minQty` works. However, a few issues - Add to Cart doesn’t work at all if product cart item quantity >= `minQty`,  subtracting from cart under `minQty` still let’s user get less then `minQty`

Comment: Okay I figured out the [addVariantToCart](https://pastebin.com/raw/K4XkMRC8) (check link for code). It looks like `product.model.selectedQuantity` was getting set to whatever the amount was needed to get to `minQty` and we have to reset it so it doesn't cause issues. Now just have to figure out how to get `updateItemQuantity` to work.

Comment: I think the main issue is `$(node).find('iframe').contents().find('.shopify-buy__btn')` can't be found. We gotta figure out how to update the product quantity from within `updateItemQuantity` function.

Comment: @bryan I'm eating my breakfast right now, then I'll be driving for nearly an hour, but when I get to work I'll take another look at this. I noticed somethings I could improve, but the hardest part so far is proving to be the ability to remove the kitten from the cart.

Comment: Awesome! Check out my [addVariantToCart](https://pastebin.com/raw/K4XkMRC8) because it work's flawlessly after extensive testing.

Comment: @bryan Think I may have just figured it out. Give me like 30 minutes to test it all and write up the edit.

Comment: @bryan I've edited my post. I've got to get back to work now, but definitely let me know if anything isn't working. After all this I have a pretty good understanding of how Buy Button work's internally so I can probably fix any issues. Phew, that's the longest time I've ever spent answering a SO question ;)

Comment: Oh gross I just noticed I said "work's". Please ignore that rogue apostrophe and pretend it never happened.

Comment: Thanks for you're help man. I appreciate it a lot. For some reason it doesn't always work when using `setProductQuantity`. I haven't been able to figure out why it doesn't fire all the time. A lot of the time it will go down below 4 and not remove it and sometimes it will work perfectly. It's very confusing.

Another big problem I've run into is we are assuming we are on the product page of specific button. It might be important to note this. The Add to Cart button can be accessed anywhere. So localstorage will probably be key. Don't worry about that though, I'll update the answer later on.

Comment: @bryan Is it the event that doesn't fire reliably? You can test by putting `console.log('hello')` inside the `updateItemQuantity` event. It might be worth noting that if the page hasn't finished loading you might be able to lower the quantity below `minQty`.

Comment: Sorry, it might have been user error. This is awesome! You rock man. So since you're a pro now - last question. I know the updated quantity relies of the `click();` of the Add to Cart button. What do you suppose I should do to counter-act the fact that a user might be updated the quantity when he/she is not on the product page with the actual button anymore?

Comment: @bryan Great! I was worried it was going to be some nightmare bug I couldn't diagnose :P So the updated quantity only relies on the click when you've clicked the Add to Cart button. The current version of the code doesn't do anything with the Add to Cart button when you're changing the quantity from your cart.

Comment: Scratch that, the Add to Cart button is never programmatically clicked with the current code in my answer.

Comment: Ahh you're right! Okay so I just gotta figure out how to store minQty elsewhere other then the Add to Cart button when an item is added to the cart. I think I can figure that out after all your leg work haha

Comment: @bryan Aha I see what you mean. Well you can easily get the id of the product (which I believe is hardcoded so will be consistent) with `product.id[0]`. You could just store the minimum quantity in (as you say) localstorage and refer to it with the product's id. I can attempt to edit my question to demonstrate this if you want, but I'm no expert in localstorage and I don't have time right now.

Comment: Nah, you've done enough man. I will ping you when I've completed it and maybe you can update your answer at a later date.

Comment: @bryan Cool, sure thing! Glad to be of help. Hopefully you can get your store going :D